# Ищу пример использования LayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Можете привести пример использования кода внутри viewWillLayoutSubviews или viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Как я понял из документации, внутри LayoutSubviews (к началу работы? к концу?) у фреймов появляются реальные размеры (через ограничения) и можно их поменять.

Но нормального примера я найти не смог.

Comment: Лучше опишите проблему которую вы пытаетесь решить. Я использую этот метод при создании cornerRadius в динамический UIView. Так-как constraints уже прописаны.

Comment: @ВикторМишустин На собеседовании попросили подробно рассказать про LayoutSubviews и привести пример его использования. Я довольно долго искал, но ничего внятного и четкого не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось достаточно просто.

Порядок вызовов методов жизненного цикла UIViewController такой:

1. viewDidLoad
2. viewWillAppear
3. viewWillLayoutSubviews
4. viewDidLayoutSubviews
5. viewDidAppear

Причем при вызове viewWillLayoutSubviews мы еще не имеем реальных координат/размеров фреймов, с учетом constraints, а в viewDidLayoutSubviews уже у нас реальные координаты, причем мы их можем там легко менять.

Если мы поменяем координаты/размеры в viewDidAppear, где у нас уже реальные координаты/размеры, то на экране с множеством элементов мы увидим "прыгание" элементов.

Поэтому координаты стоит менять именно в viewDidLayoutSubviews, т.к. в этом месте мы уже можем получить реальные координаты/размеры окружающих элементы, но элементы еще не отобразились пользователю. viewDidLayoutSubviews стоит использовать когда координаты/размеры какого-то элемента зависят от координат или размеров других элементов и заранее эти размеры трудно посчитать.

Answer (score 1):

Просмотрите в этой статье. [iOS swift — setNeedsLayout vs layoutIfNeeded vs layoutSubviews()](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/ios-swift-setneedslayout-vs-layoutifneeded-vs-layoutsubviews-5a2b486da31c)